# Sum total amount returned from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query below that is returning individual sales records with amounts  for each order placed for a specific product SKU. How would I go about summing the total amount? The column is "extprice" that I need to sum. Any help would be appreciated, thanks...

```
select       partno4pt,orders.orderdate,orders.processdate,orderdetails.qty,orderdetails.extprice
from orderdetails
inner join  orders
on orderdetails.order_id = orders.order_id
where orderdate > '2009.01.17 09:00:00' 
and partnumber like '%m9150%' 
and orders.processdate is not null
```

Comment: @JackM: If you're going to ask someone to format their code, at least provide a link to the markdown reference so they know what you're talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the SUM aggregate function:

```
select partno4pt,orders.orderdate,orders.processdate,orderdetails.qty,orderdetails.extprice, 
    SUM(orderdetails.extprice) AS sumprice from orderdetails 
    inner join orders on orderdetails.order_id = orders.order_id 
    where orderdate > '2009.01.17 09:00:00' 
    and partnumber like '%m9150%' and orders.processdate is not null 
        GROUP BY partno4pt,orders.orderdate,orders.processdate,orderdetails.qty,orderdetails.extprice
```

Comment: The SUM will based on the `GROUP BY` - you'd get the SUM between identical `ORDERDATE`, `PROCESSDATE`, and `QTY`.  The OP didn't provide details, but it's unlikely your query will return the expected value.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming a simple answer here due to it being a simple question:

```
select SUM(orderdetails.extprice)
from orderdetails inner join orders on orderdetails.order_id = orders.order_id
where orderdate > '2009.01.17 09:00:00' and
partnumber like '%m9150%' and orders.processdate is not null
```